# jetpack compose Scaffold Possible to override the standard durations of SnackBar?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar, scaffold

How can override the standard durations of the Scaffold SnackBar to apply my own durations in MS. I can't see a way to do it

```
is EventsToAddAlbumScreen.ShowSnackbarEventToAddAlbumScreen -> scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                    message = event.message,
                    duration = SnackbarDuration.Short // <-- want to change this to 500ms for example
                )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `SnackbarDuration.Indefinite` and cancel it manually after the necessary delay:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    val job = launch {
        scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar("Hi", duration = SnackbarDuration.Indefinite)
    }
    delay(500)
    job.cancel()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick:

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val snackBarMessage = stringResource(id = R.string.snackbar_message)

scope.launch {
    val job = scope.launch {
        snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
            message = snackBarMessage,
            duration = SnackbarDuration.Indefinite,
        )
    }
    delay(500)
    job.cancel()
}
```